# Does the kubernetes cluster auto scaler for Azure work with VMs not in a VMSS?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I understand the [kubernetes cluster auto scaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler) in Azure works with VM Scale Sets. However, I do not see mention of it working with VMs not in scale sets. In the README it only mentions scale sets. s

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by setting the VMType to [Standard](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/README.md).